# ajax xhr.responseText when result contains @ error uncaught typeerror

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I do ajax call via new XMLHttpRequest();

when I do this

```
var params = "x="+encodeURIComponent(x);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("POST", "....php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        $("#divID").html(e.currentTarget.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send(params);
```

It is fine and working well..... but when the result contains @ I get this error in console log

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null without using removeChild
```

to clarify : example :

when the php gives `<img src="..." />` -->> it's ok

when the php gives `some text blablabla ...blalbla contact allo@test.com` -->> I get the error

why and do I need to fix it ???

Regards

Comment: it doesnt make sense. You'll need to make sure that the response text is a valid html string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "workable" solution

in the php of the ajax call I do only one echo and replace any occurence of @ to &commat

```
$stuff = ...; // gathering what to echo
$stuff .= ...; // gathering what to echo
$stuff = str_replace('@','&commat;',$stuff); 
echo $stuff;
```

that way the browser shows @ and the error don't appear in console log

note : I tried to replace in javascript level (e.currentTarget.responseText) but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

As in ajax you are sending plain html code. I would suggest you to use the json format
on ajax response. this will solve your problem

Comment: Hi, is there an other "Content-Type" `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` ??
I tried `text/html;charset=UTF-8` but the ajax call doesn't work

Comment: I think you need to try with Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: in my case `application/json; charset=utf-8` doesn't work :(